# Javascript array for auto-complete

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, autocomplete

I implemented a auto-complete function that takes an array as parameter.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#empf').autocomplete(['black', 'white', 'red']);
}
```

Now I do not want a **static array**. Outside the document ready function I declared a function that retrieves the colors from local storage. I call this function in document ready function.

So everytime the user enters new input I want to put it in the array and use that **array  globally**. Is that possible?

For **initialisation** of the array, at any point I know the number of colores stored.

So instead of the static array I put a variable e.g. data and I declare data as an array. I tried it this way:

```
var colors;

$(document).ready(function(){
        loadColors();
        $('#empf').autocomplete(colors);
}

function loadColors(){
 colors = new Array(getNumColor()));
//in a loop save the colors to array using colors[i] = ...
}
```

But this causes my application to crash. Any ideas?

Any ideas?

Comment: What do you mean by crash? Are you getting an error message?

Comment: It breaks the interaction with the UI, the UI is just frozzen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems to be an issue with parenthesis.

It should be

```
colors = new Array(getNumColor());
```

instead of

```
colors = new Array(getNumColor()));
```

Answer (score 2):

Like Rahul said this seems to be an issue of parenthesis. With [firebug](http://encosia.com/2009/09/21/updated-see-how-i-used-firebug-to-learn-jquery/)([another link](http://ejohn.org/blog/hacking-digg-with-firebug-and-jquery/)) it is easier to detect/debug these bugs.

Also I think you should use [jquery ui's autocomplete](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#default) if you are not already using it(I am not sure if you are using it).